# How to print data of _RecordSet to the text file in delphi 10

Tags: delphi, ado, delphi-10.1-berlin

how to print all data/records contain in Recordset to the text file in Delphi 10 ?
I could not able to find any Method or property for it.Please guide, i am newbie in delphi.

I have done following:

```
Var:
    CurrField : Field;
    RecSet:_RecordSet ;
Begin:
    RecSet:= command.Execute(records,Params,-1);
    CurrField := RecSet.Fields[0];
end;
```

but i want to print complete records/data contain in RecSet(_RecordSet type)  in text file.

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear. Do you want to print something to a printer or a pdf file (or some such), or do you want to write text to a **text** file? Could you post more of your code? What is _RecordSet or RecordSet? A database record, a Delphi record type, what? I **guess** you are looking for a report program/tool. But if so, then your question is far too broad and off-topic.

Comment: I have mentioned in question that i need to print data in text file means write data of RecSet to the text file.  About _Recordset is an ADO Type Object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write it yourself. If the recordset is relatively small, the easiest way is to use a TStringList.

```
var
  i: Integer;
  s: string;
  SL: TStringList;
begin
  SL := TStringList.Create;
  try
    while not RecSet.Eof do
    begin
      // Clear string for the next row
      s := '';
      // Loop through the fields in this row, creating a comma-separated list
      for i := 0 to RecSet.FieldCount - 1 do
        s := s + RecSet.Fields[i].Value + ',';
      // Remove unnecessary final comma at end
      SetLength(s, Length(s) - 1); 
      // Add to the stringlist
      SL.Add(s);
    end;
    // Save the stringlist content to disk
    SL.SaveToFile('YourFileName.txt');
  finally
    SL.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Ken, could you please help me for how to write  TOleEnum type variable value in file ?

Comment: Just typecast it to an integer, and then use `IntToStr()` to convert it to text.